Usar clave foránea en mciroservicios separados usando JPA y springboot
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación sencilla usando la arquitectura de microservicios usando JPA y una API REST con spring boot y llegué a un punto donde no se cual es la mejor forma para tratar con las claves foráneas que se propagan entre clases en microservicios distintos.
La idea es que tengo un microservicio de compra o pedido el cual gestiona los mismos. En una de sus clases recibe la id de el cliente que realiza el pedido, pero este cliente es modelado en otro microservicio con el mismo nombre.
Aquí es donde entra mi pregunta de cuál sería la forma en que se podría hacer esto ya que si uso las anotaciones @onetoone indicando que es una clave foránea me pide hacer una “instancia” de clase de la cual se recibe esta id pero como mencioné esta se encuentra en un microservicio diferente y me encuentro estancado en este punto.

Para tu capa de persistencia no tiene sentido marcarlo como clave foránea, ya que no tienes la tabla "clientes" en tu microservicio. Es simplemente un valor más que no tiene un significado especial en este contexto.
Es en tu capa de negocio o dominio donde debes gestionar qué hacer con ese valor: ¿Simplemente usar el ID? ¿Pedir al microservicio "Clientes" los datos del cliente con ese ID?
Este último caso quizá deba realizarlo incluso otro microservicio que haga de agregador, sumando la información obtenida de "Clientes" y "Pedidos"
